# Kubernetes: how to do dynamic PersistentVolumeClaim with persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Reclaim

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a dynamic `PersistentVolume` provisioned using `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

I would like to keep the PV after the pod is done. So I would like to have what `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain` does.

However, that is applicable to `PersistentVolume`, not `PersistentVolumeClaim` (AFAIK).

**How can I change this behavior for dynamically provisioned PV's?**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}-pvc
spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    storageClassName: gp2
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 6Gi

---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-gatling-test"
spec:
    restartPolicy: Never
    containers:
      - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-gatling-test
        image: ".../services-api-mvn-builder:latest"
        command: ["sh", "-c", 'mvn -B gatling:test -pl csa-testing -DCSA_SERVER={{ template "project.fullname" . }} -DCSA_PORT={{ .Values.service.appPort }}']
        volumeMounts:
          - name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-test-res"
            mountPath: "/tmp/testResults"

    volumes:
      - name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-test-res"
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: "{{ .Release.Name }}-pvc"
          #persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain  ???
```

Answer (score 9):

Workaround would be to create new StorageClass with `reclaimPolicy: Retain` and use that StorageClass every where.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gp2-retain
  annotations:
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4 
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

PS: The reclaimPolicy of the existing StorageClass can't edited, but you can delete the StorageClass and recreate it with `reclaimPolicy: Retain`

Comment: The problem with this, is that I now went from something portable (`storageClassName: default`) to introducing something AWS specific by hard-coding `provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs`. :-(

Comment: Correct, You can also change the default storage class to this one if required.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't declare a `StorageClass` where the only thing I declare is `reclaimPolicy: Retain` so my .yaml files will be portable.

Answer (score 9):

This is not the answer to the OP, but the answer to the personal itch that led me here is that I don't need `reclaimPolicy: Retain` at all. I need a [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) instead. Read on if this is for you:

My itch was to have a `PersistentVolume` that got re-used over and over by the container in a persistent way; the way that is the default behavior when using `docker` and `docker-compose` volumes. So that a new `PersistentVolume` only gets created once:

```
# Create a new PersistentVolume the very first time
kubectl apply  -f my.yaml 

# This leaves the "volume" - the PersistentVolume - alone
kubectl delete -f my.yaml

# Second and subsequent times re-use the same PersistentVolume
kubectl apply  -f my.yaml
```

And I thought the way to do that was to declare a `PersistentVolumeClaim` with `reclaimPolicy: Retain` and then reference that in my deployment. But even when i got `reclaimPolicy: Retain` working, a brand new `PersistentVolume` still got created on every `kubectl apply`. `reclaimPolicy: Retain` just ensured that the old ones didn't get deleted.

But no. The way to achieve this use-case is with a [`StatefulSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/). It is way simpler, and then it behaves like I'm used to with docker and docker-compose.

Comment: Neither `Retain` policy nor `StatefulSets` are required to re-use data between `Pod` runs (both are good practice though, e.g. for databases). it's enough to split your stateful app's config into *two YAML files*: single-use for PVC provisioning, and multi-use for provisioning other - more variable - resources such as `Deployments`.

Answer (score 6):

you can config it in pv.yaml or storageclass.yaml or take a patch to exit pv

pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

storageclass.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gp2-retain
  annotations:
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4 
reclaimPolicy: Retain
```

take a patch

```
kubectl patch pv <your-pv-name> -p '{"spec":{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}}'
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to patch an already-provisioned volume. This is useful when you don't want to destroy a volume created with the wrong policy.

Answer (score 4):

[There](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30606) is an issue on Kubernetes Github about Reclaim Policy of dynamically provisioned volumes.

A short answer is "no" - you cannot set the policy.

Here is the small quote from the dialogue in the ticket on how to avoid the  PV deletion:

> **Speedline**: Stumbled upon this and I'm going through a similar issue. I want to create an Elasticsearch cluster but make sure that if the cluster goes down for whatever reason, the data stored on the persistent disks get maintained across the restart. I currently have one a PersistentVolumeClaim for each of the deployment of elasticsearch that carries data.
>
> **jsafrane**: @speedplane: it is maintained as long as you don't delete the PVC. Reclaim policy is executed only if kuberenetes sees a PV that was bound to a PVC and the PVC does not exist.
>
> **@jsafrane** okay, got it. So just have to be careful with the PVCs, deleting one is like deleting all the data on the disk.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, this is within `helm test`, and Helm deletes all resources at the end. The project is iced but I'll try later..